# Closed Form for an Infinite Summation

Tags: sequences-and-series

Let $p$ be prime, and let $0\le j\le p-1$.  I would like to find a closed expression for the infinite sum
$$f(p,j)=\sum_{i=0}^{\infty}\frac{p^i}{(pi+j)!}$$
Initial computations show that $f(2,0)=\cosh\sqrt2-1$ and $f(2,1)=\frac{\sinh\sqrt 2}{\sqrt 2}-1$.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Recallin the [Mittag-Leffler function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mittag-Leffler_function)

$$E_{\alpha,\beta}(z)= \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \frac{z^k}{\Gamma(\alpha k+\beta)}.  $$

Your series will be readily expressed in terms of the above function as

$$ f(p,j)=\sum_{i=0}^{\infty}\frac{p^i}{(pi+j)!}= \sum_{i=0}^{\infty}\frac{p^i}{\Gamma(pi+j+1)} = E_{p,j+1}(p). $$.

Note that, $n!=\Gamma(n+1)$.

Comment: Making this connection is very helpful.  Thank you.  Is anything known about the special value $E_{p,j+1}(p)$?  Or do we know how they multiply, i.e., do we know the value of $E_{p,j+1}(p)\cdot E_{q,k+1}(q)$ in terms of other values of Mittag-Leffler functions?

Comment: @Jared: In general, multiplying two Mittag-Leffler functions does not belong to the same class of functions.